# What could be the possible equivalent of following Chef recipe to Ansible?

Tags: chef-infra, ansible

Here is the chef recipe that I want to convert into Ansible. What could be the possible equivalent of it ?
I have the path and url.

```
remote_file 'abc_artifact' do
  path abc_artifact_path
  source node[:base][:agent][:abc_url] % {
    :version => node[:base][:agent][:agent_version],
    :env => environment
  }
  checksum node[:base][:agent][:agent_sha256]
  notifies :run, 'execute[unzip_abc_artifact]', :immediately
  action :create_if_missing
end
```

Here is the second part,

where " node.run_state[:abc] ||= Mash.new "

```
case node[:platform_family]
  when "debian"
    abc_attributes = node[:abc][:default].merge(node[:abcone][:agent]).merge(:username=>node.run_state[:abc][:abc_username])
    abc_url = im_abc_url(Mash.new(abc_attributes.to_hash))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick and easy solution:

```yaml
vars:
  source: "https://mydomain/myapp/1.0.0.zip"
  abc_artifact: /path/to/my/file.zip
  agent_sha256: 17054df9a6b887dbba25...
tasks:
  - name: download abc artifact
    get_url:
      url: "{{ source }}"
      dest: "{{ abc_artifact }}"
      sha256sum: "{{ agent_sha256 }}"
    notify: unzip abc artifact
handlers:
 - name: unzip abc artifact
   shell: "unzip -f {{ abc_artifact }}" # or whatever
```

That was easy. OK, I will try to explain some things to consider:

## String Formatting

```ruby
source node[:base][:agent][:abc_url] % {
  :version => node[:base][:agent][:agent_version],
  :env => environment
}
```

You can use the [`format` jinja2 filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#format) for that. See the [python string formatting documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) for more details. But it could be something like the following:

```yaml
vars:
  source: "https://%(env).mydomain/myapp/%(version)s.zip"
  agent_version: 1.0.0
  env: dev
tasks:
    - name: download abc artifact
      get_url:
        url: "{{ source|format(**{'version': agent_version, 'env': env }) }}"
```

## Notifications

```ruby
notifies :run, 'execute[unzip_abc_artifact]', :immediately
```

Normally you should use handlers for that:

```yaml
tasks:
  - name: download abc artifact
    get_url: # [...]
    notify: unzip abc artifact
handlers:
 - name: unzip abc artifact
   shell: "unzip -f {{ abc_artifact }}"
```

But you can also use [playbook conditionals](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html) if you require it to be *immediate*:

```yaml
tasks:
  - name: download abc artifact
    get_url: # [...]
    register: abc_artifact_download
  - name: unzip abc artifact
    shell: "unzip -f {{ abc_artifact }}"
    when: abc_artifact_download|changed
```

The only problem I see here is that if the zip file exists but it has not been extracted, the unzip task will not run. This problem also exists in your chef example. Maybe you can check if a specific file has been extracted instead.

## Create If Missing

```ruby
action :create_if_missing
```

If you need to keep this behavior for whatever reason, use [the `stat` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/stat_module.html) and [playbook conditionals](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html) for that:

```yaml
tasks:
  - name: check if abc_artifact_stat exists
    stat: path={{ abc_artifact }}
    register: abc_artifact_stat
  - name: download abc artifact
    get_url: # [...]
    when: not abc_artifact_stat.stat.exists
```

Comment: I have added the second part of my chef recipe and i don't understand the merge part in those. How can I convert those in Ansible ?

Comment: That code merges hashes/dictionaries. The run_state is like a *global variable dictonary* in Chef. That code is very Chef specific. Cannot be translated to Ansible as it is. The `abc_attributes` seems to be a dictionary with some configuration values, including one key for the username. Then those values are used to generate some kind of URL.

Comment: How can I generate the Url from those specific configuration values using Ansible ?

Comment: I don't know, you need to read the `im_abc_url` function implementation.